# How to run a Python file that requires external data in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to run a Python file in VSC but the file requires external data from two different .txt files.

As an example, if I run it in the Python IDLE, I'd open the Python file, select Run...Customized, and enter the path to the .txt file, (e.g. data/xxxxx.txt data/yyyy.txt output.png) and then run it.

Could you please indicate if there is a way to run a file in that way in VSC, or refer me to where I can find any supportive documentation that would cover this special requirement?

### This is the function where the exception occurs:

```
def main():

    # Check usage
    if len(sys.argv) not in [3, 4]:
        sys.exit("Usage: python generate.py structure words [output]")

    # Parse command-line arguments
    structure = sys.argv[1]
    words = sys.argv[2]
    output = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv) == 4 else None

    # Generate crossword
    crossword = Crossword(structure, words)
    creator = CrosswordCreator(crossword)
    assignment = creator.solve()

    # Print result
    if assignment is None:
        print("No solution.")
    else:
        creator.print(assignment)
        if output:
            creator.save(assignment, output)
```

### And this is the exception in VSC:

```
Exception has occurred: SystemExit

Usage: python myfile.py structure words [output]

  File "/Users/#######/myfile.py", line 277, in main
    sys.exit("Usage: python myfile.py structure words [output]")   
 File "/Users//#######/myfile.py", line 299, in <module>
   main()
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to create a _launch configuration_ with VS code?

Comment: In the `launch.json` set the `cwd` to the location  you want

Comment: To M. Spiller, thanks but I'm not sure a launch configuration is the answer, but I'll have a better look at that in the documentation. Thanks

Comment: To rioV8. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll need to have a better look at how the launch.json works, but at the moment I couldn't find the way to make it work as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to run your python file with the VS Code Debugger, but can't tell it what arguments to launch your program with.

Navigate to the debugger tab (Ctrl / Cmd + Shift + D) and click on "Create a launch.json file", specifying in an appearing prompt that you want to add launch configurations to a python file.

[image: Screenshot to create a launch.json file]

It should create and open a boilerplate json file. Inside the first element of `"configurations"` you then can add a key `"args"` with all the necessary arguments inside an array.

In full, the json file may look something like this:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",

            // this is what I added manually
            "args": [
                "a.txt",
                "b.txt",
                "out.png"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, when you have your python file open, launch it either through the debug tab or with the green arrow in the top right corner.

EDIT:

With frequently changing command line arguments, you can tell VS Code to [prompt](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/issues/108#issuecomment-581815593) you for those. See the following json. If there's something you don't understand, let me know.

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "${input:firstArg}",
                "${input:secondArg}",
                "out.png"
            ]
        }
    ],

    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "firstArg",
            "type": "promptString",
            "default": "myDefault.txt",
            "description": "First txt"
        },
        {
            "id": "secondArg",
            "type": "promptString",
            "description": "Now your second txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the complete and clear explanation. I think you put me on the right path now. I'm at work, but I'll try your solution later and get back to you with the results. Thanks

Comment: It worked beautifully! Many thanks. I had the launch.json file created but without the args. Once I added the args I could run it w/o problems.  Now there is the minor complication that I have to change the args every time I need to run the Python file with other arguments, but I can live with that. Thank you

Comment: You can tell VS Code to prompt you for command line arguments. See my edit :)

Comment: That's great. I think I've got the idea, so I'll give it a try with different files. Now, it's all good to come here and find a solution thanks to people like you, but may I ask you how did you learn all these details of VSC? I've been though the documentation and videos and they are not clear enough, at least for me. Thanks

Comment: Honestly I only knew a little bit about launch configurations and only assumed that there must be a way to specify the arguments before running it, so googling did most of it for me (the URL I got the answer from is also in my edit :). For more about launch configurations you can check attributes and variable substitution here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

Comment: You googled it just to help me with my question? Wow! The world is not in such a bad shape as I believed. Many thanks for your support. I'll continue investigating the VSC docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python seperately for VSC as it is an extension.

After installing :

```
python filename.py
```

For more details: [VS code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Comment: I already have Python installed in my computer Akshat, as well as the Python extension in VSC. Can you clarify your instruction after installing? It looks like running Python in the terminal. Thanks